# PHP parser error for '?>' and '<?php' within an if block

Tags: php, apache2

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
/* some code */
    function blah() {
        /* some code */
        if (!$book || !$txt) {
?>
<h1>Page Error</h1>
<p>This is not a valid page</p>
<?php
            return;
        }
?>
<h1>Check Page</h1>
<p>Data:<?php print '<a href="'.wl($page).'">'.$page.'</a>'; ?></p>
<?php
        /* some code */
    }
/* some code */
```

On server A it always returns `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /blah/blah.php on line 474` (474 is the line of the ?> just before `<h1>Check Page</h1>`) while it works find on another server B.

The version in `PHP Version 5.5.5-1+debphp.org~precise+2` on my server A and `PHP Version 5.4.20` on server B.

It seems that I missed some configuration? Or there's some bug or feature I haven't notice? Anyone has an idea?

**Edit:**

This problem is temporarily solved after I replaced the:

```
?>
<h1>Page Error</h1>
<p>This is not a valid page</p>
<?php
```

With this:

```
            print <<<'EOF'
<h1>Page Error</h1>
<p>This is not a valid page</p>
EOF;
```

But I'd still like to know why this happens.

Comment: This works ok for me on 5.5.5. Does this *exact* snippet give you an error?

Comment: does it have to look like this, because its not the most readable code in existence.

Comment: @Alex Almost, I just replaced the Chinese text in the html part with the English version.

Comment: @Tom Do you have some suggestion about the coding style for something like this? Any I'd like to know why.

Comment: Instead of breaking up the function with <?php try assigning it to a var then return. So $html .= "<h1>Page Error</h1>"; return $html; echo out the function.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it and i found this the other day. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I still cannot figure out why the original code just worked in some machine and not the others, if it was really a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are not closing the function neither the `if`:

```
<?php
/* some code */
function blah() {
    /* some code */
    if (!$book || !$txt) {
?>

<h1>Page Error</h1>
<p>This is not a valid page</p>
<?php
        return;
    }
?>
<h1>Check Page</h1>
<p>Data:<?php print '<a href="'.wl($page).'">'.$page.'</a>'; ?></p>
<?php
    /* some code */
}
/* some code */
```

Instead, you should do:

```
<?php
/* some code */
function blah() {
    /* some code */
    if (!$book || !$txt) {

        return;
    }    

echo "<h1>Page Error</h1>";
echo "<p>This is not a valid page</p>";

echo "<h1>Check Page</h1>";
echo '<p>Data: <a href="'.wl($page).'">'.$page.'</a></p>';

    /* some code */
}
/* some code */
```